# E: Unable to locate package - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache-zookeeper, apt-get, package-managers

I've being trying to install Zookeeper in my laptop. According to the installation commands Zookeeper provides the apt-get package to install:

```
sudo apt-get install zookeeper
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install zookeeper-server
```

it returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package zookeeper-server
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `sudo apt-get install zookeeperd` instant of `sudo apt-get install zookeeper`
When you use `zookeeperd` zookeeper server will be created and started automaticly

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an apt repository to your Ubuntu installation so that the zookeeper-server package gets found.

In case you about to install zookeeper as part of a Cloudera CDH installation, you have to create a file cloudera.list into your /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory as described [here](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_cdh5_install.html#topic_4_4_2).

If you just copy and the commands, be sure to verify that the file and repository key have been created. Sometimes multiple commands are specified and separated by \ or $. Execute them separately in the terminal.

If the repository has been added correctly, zookeeper-server will be found after doing "sudo apt-get update".

Answer (score -1):

The result tells you that there is no zookeeper-server in the archive that you subscribed too. Maybe you need to add a third party repository for that package.